# Self-deletion of questions that are referenced by others' answers

Tags: discussion, questions

I've been searching about "Memory usage on iPhone" on Stack Overflow before I ask a question. I found the question [Programmatically retrieve memory usage on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787160/programmatically-retrieve-memory-usage-on-iphone). I tried to find my solution under this question, but when I followed [the link in pgb's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728876/freememory-vs-instruments-memory-monitor) I was redirected to a page saying:

> This question was voluntarily removed by its author.

I understand what it means, but is there not any mechanism to force an author not to delete his question because it's a reference for another question?

Comment: No, but this is a good reason **why link-only answers are not answers**. :)

Comment: Couldn't it have only been removed by the author if it had no answers yet? I might be mistaken, but that would render the value of the question linked to probably quite low.

Comment: @Bart: There were two answers with a score of 0, but it was deleted way back in September '09. Not sure what the deleting rules were back then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea why he was referring you to that question anyway. It doesn't really contain any information of value, which helps to explain why the answers received no upvotes and why the question was deleted in the first place.

The answers are:

> Haven't tried FreeMemory, but my guess is you have a Zombie infestation. Instruments only sees live applications

and

> As an aside, you can replicate the free-memory-measurement behavior of FreeMemory using a few Mach VM calls, as Landon Fuller provides code for [here](http://landonf.bikemonkey.org/code/iphone/Determining_Available_Memory.20081203.html). I imagine you could extend this to list running processes using other Mach calls, fully duplicating FreeMemory's capabilities.

The only useful content is the link in the second answer, and pgb reproduces that link in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/787174/366904).

Of course, I don't think that's a very good idea… We've already seen a perfect demonstration of why [link-only answers are not very useful](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers):

> ...one should try and give the answer (even if the answer is 'no, it can't be done' or 'no, I don't think it can be done' -- very different answers) and then if you have a link that explains it, go ahead and post it within the answer...